# Find out glibc compilation options

Tags: linux, compiling, gcc, glibc

I want to find out which compiler/linker options were used to compile the GNU C Standard Library (glibc) when installing Linux. In particular I want to get the same result of the archive libc.a when compiling glibc from source on a different machine (same version of gcc, make, binutils, etc though).

All I could find out was the used gcc version with:

```
user@ubuntu:/$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.21-0ubuntu4) stable release version 2.21,
...
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.9.2.
...
```

But when compiling glibc from source with no further options I don't get the same results after running make. The self compiled `libc.a` archive is different from the preinstalled one (size and binary wise). So I guess there is some optimization going on. Maybe because of included debug information when compiled from source.

Build:

```
user@ubuntu:~/glibc$ sudo apt-get source libc6
user@ubuntu:~/glibc/glibc-build$ sudo ../glibc-2.21/configure --prefix=/home/user/glibc/glibc-install/
...
sudo make
...
```

In the debian/rules file and in the output I found, that `-O2` and `-g` is used with gcc.

There is an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015276/how-to-view-glibc-compilation-options), which I looked at but didn't help me.

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04, but I need it on other (non debian) systems also. Furthermore it should also work with eglibc on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

The final goal is to reproduce (compile) every version of glibc used on different systems (I know that's a lot) and make IDA PRO FLIRT signatures out of them. So, in conclusion I need the same binary output at least for `libc.a` (that's the file the signatures are made from). Further reading on FLIRT Signatures [here](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/index.shtml).

The Problem with these Signatures is, that every different compiler version and every compiler option can change the output of the Library archive and lead to a different Signature which will only partially work on the analyzed binary.

I'm new to this, so every help is welcome. I hope i didn't forget to mention something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find everything you need to rebuild in the src.deb package that matches you `.deb` package. Look at `apt-src(8)`.

Comment: What's the difference of using `apt-src` compared to `apt-get source` and then running `make` beside of having a .deb file for the installation?

Comment: Well, I tried it and apparently the libc.a in the .deb file has exactly the same size but a different md5 sum. I'll try creating FLIRT Signatures now and see if they're the same. Btw. building the .deb files took a lot of time.

Comment: Can you validate my answer if it helped you to rebuild your binary with the same options ?

Comment: I want to test different versions and systems too, and it worked also with downloading `apt-get download libc6-dev` (same md5 hashes also). My Problem is that I still don't know the compilation options, which was the original question.

Comment: The compilations options are in the source package. Unpack the package, then have a look at the `debian/rules` file. You should find the options used to compile.